# PHP first active button

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little question for you!

I make a selection from mysql my buttons for example:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from navigation");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo '<a href="?id=$row['id']">$row['name']</a>';

}
```

so I call all the navigation from mysql and I have a class in css which is called as .active, this class make a active button when I click it, but how can I make the first button active?

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from navigation");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

     if ($row['id'] == $_GET['id'])) {
         echo '<a class="active" href="?id=$row['id']">$row['name']</a>';
     } else {
         echo '<a href="?id=$row['id']">$row['name']</a>';
     }

}
```

Comment: Your echo statements aren't correct and will throw a parse error. Don't know if it was just a cut and paste error in posting the question, but you use single quotes to start the string, but you attempt to inject `$row`. PHP will only allow that with double quotes, so it will see your single quotes for `$row['id']` and seeing the first single quote, think you want to end the string.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
<?PHP
$query = mysql_query("select * from navigation");
$first = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ((!array_key_exists('id', $_GET) && $first) || $row['id'] == $_GET['id']) {
         $extra = 'class="active"';
         $first = false;
    } else
         $extra = '';

    echo "<a $extra href=\"?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Kudos for pointing out the uselessness in having an if condition for each link :P

Comment: @Geoffrey, I try to say something, the active statement is ready, I've done it now, but I set can we make the first button active before we click it. I mean default button "home"

Comment: @Mike, this will make the first button active if "id" is not set in $_GET.